# How to get rid of these warning?

Tags: c++, function

```
bool Order::add(std::istream& is){
   int copies;
   bool keepgoing = true;

   while (keepgoing){   
      std::cout << "Quantity (0 to quit) : ";
      is >> copies;  
      if (copies==0){
         keepgoing = false;
         return false;

      }else if (copies<0){
         std::cout << "Enter a positive number. Try again."<<std::endl;
      }else{
         no_copies+=copies;
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

It showing warning that the control may reach end of non-void function.
Am not getting it.

Comment: Proper indentation please.

Comment: If the control reaches into the `else if` part, there is no `return`, hence the warning.

Comment: @karma_geek It's inside a `while` loop that will continue in that case, though.

Comment: What do you return if copies < 0?

Comment: Make it while(true) and get rid of keeping

Answer (score 3):

The whole `keepgoing` business is redundant—you only ever set it to `false` just before exiting the function anyway. Replace it with a "forever" loop and the warning should disappear:

```
bool Order::add(std::istream& is){
   int copies;

   for(;;) {
      std::cout << "Quantity (0 to quit) : ";
      is >> copies;  
      if (copies==0){
         return false;
      }else if (copies<0){
         std::cout << "Enter a positive number. Try again."<<std::endl;
      }else{
         no_copies+=copies;
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Note that you're not checking that the input succeeded, which you always should.

Comment: Moreover, for(;;) is more efficient than while(true).

Comment: @szulak Really? I don't believe *any* compiler worth its salt produces different code for those two.

Comment: @szulak If so, throw the compiler out of the window.

Comment: @szulak Can you give any compiler where they don't generate the exact same code, and where concerns about efficiency are meaningful?

Comment: I've seen such statement on the SO, but it was assumed a compilation without any optimisation.

Comment: @szulak I would say these should be equivalent even in non-optimising mode.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, your code is too complicated for your compiler to give more useful warnings.

You've added a `keepgoing` variable that doesn't add anything. In all cases where you meaningfully use its value, its value will be `true`. However, the compiler is unable to determine that it will always be `true` in all relevant cases, and accounts for the possibility that it unexpectedly gets set to false. Who knows, maybe your compiler supports you modifying the variable using a debugger.

As noted already, you can easily get rid of that variable: your `return` statement will cause the `while` loop to be exited, regardless of that `while` loop's condition.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `return` statement after

```
     keepgoing = false;
```

to the end.

```
     return false;
```

Like:

```
bool Order::add(std::istream& is){
   int copies;
   bool keepgoing = true;

   while (keepgoing){   
      std::cout << "Quantity (0 to quit) : ";
      is >> copies;  
      if (copies==0){
         keepgoing = false;
         // No need to return from here.
         // Changing keepgoing to false will break the loop.
      }else if (copies<0){
         std::cout << "Enter a positive number. Try again."<<std::endl;
      }else{
         no_copies+=copies;
         return true;
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the compiler isn't very clear on its warnings.  The warning is trying to say that if your function reaches the end, you're not returning any value.  Since your while loop could conceivably exit - you're checking a bool variable rather than just saying `while (true)` - the compiler is telling you that not all paths through your code return a value, which is a bad thing.

A lot of compilers will treat `while (true)` as warnings in their own right, since they could easily lead to infinite loops.  For warning-free code, move the line

```
return false
```

from where you have it to the very end of the function.  This way, when the user enters 0 the `keepgoing` variable will break the while loop and fall to the end of the function, returning false.